# WriteFileSync is not working while saving response in .txt file in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a async function `translateText()` which return some response, I am trying to put that response in a different file where the function will call, but it is not working at all. giving error.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. 
Received an instance of Promise
```

- I have a `array ImagesNames` which contains file name.
- `detecText()` is coverting txt from Images and pass response in translateText()
- After this I am trying to use the response of `detecText()` in `TranslateText()` and response of translate text I am trying to save in .`txt file where filename` will be ImagesNames array or detecTxt parameter
- Now I am passing this array filename in `writeFileSync` where text is coming from `translateText() function`

**translateText function**

```
    const target = "en";
    
    const translateText = async function translateText(text) {
      let [translations] = await translate.translate(text, target);
      translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];
    
      translations.forEach((translation, i) => { 
        return translation;
      });
    };
```

**Using function to write response in .txt**

```
   ImagesNames.forEach((element) => {
    detecText(element)
    .then((result) => {
    texts = result;
    let imagesdir = element.replace("public/", "");
    finaltextsave = imagesdir.replace(".jpg", ".txt");
     fs.writeFileSync(finaltextsave, translateText(result));

   })
   .catch((err) => console.log(err + element));

    });
```

How Can I save this response of translateText() and parameter of detecText() as a file name for every loop running or every parameter.

**Updated as suggested by below answers -**

still getting `error` but a bit different.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView.
```

Received an instance of array.

```
 ImagesNames.forEach((element) => {
 detecText(element)
 .then(async (result) => { 
  texts = result;
  let imagesdir = element.replace('public/', '');
  finaltextsave = imagesdir.replace('.jpg', '.txt');
  fs.writeFileSync(finaltextsave, await translateText(result)); 
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err + element));
```

});

Comment: `translateText` is an async function therefore returning a `Promise`. You have to await the result of `translateText`.

Comment: @Palladium02 can you plase explain a pseudo code or elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue of cannot write `undefined` to file as `Buffer` or `String`
instance was extepected we have to take a look at the `translateText` function.
We can remove the `.forEach` as it does not do anything use because the `return`
statement is related to the callback of `.forEach` and not `translateText`.
Leaving us with the snippet below. Now `translateText` returns a `Promise` of an
array.

```js
const translateText = async function translateText(text) {
  let [translations] = await translate.translate(text, target);
  translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];

  return translations;
};
```

Every async function automatically returns a `Promise`.
Therefore the return values of `translateText` is a `Promise`.
`fs.writeFileSync` on the other hand can only work with strings or buffers.
To resolve the issue you are facing the callback of your `.then` call on `detecText`
also has to be asynchronous so you can await `translateText`.
Now that `translateText` returns `Promise<Array>` we store the array in a seperate
variable and use a looping mechanism of our choice to iterate over all translations
in `translations`. In that loop we then write each translation to it's own file
using it's position in the array as unique value for the file names.

```js
ImagesNames.forEach((element) => {
  detecText(element)
    .then(async (result) => {
      //  ^^^^^ add async here to create async context
      texts = result;
      let imagesdir = element.replace('public/', '');
      finaltextsave = imagesdir.replace('.jpg', '.txt');
      let translations = await translateText(result);
      //                 ^^^^^ add await here to wait for the translations
      translations.forEach((translation, index) => {
        let [path, extension] = finaltextsave.split('.');
        fs.writeFileSync([path, `_${index}`, '.txt'].join(''), translation);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err + element));
});
```

Comment: got error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefinedpublic/8773-20220804-1-Cover Page_5.jpg` here I am removing `public/` and `replacing .jpg` with .txt  from element to save as file name

Comment: @katemoss Is that error from the same location in your code?

Comment: this error coming from `.catch((err) => console.log(err + element));` as  err is undefined and file name is `public/8773-20220804-1-Cover Page_5.jpg`

Comment: Know I see your are passing undefined as data to `writeFileSync` as `translateText` does not return anything and therefore the value of the Promise will be `undefined`.

Comment: as you can see I am removing `public/` and replacing `.jpg` with .txt to save with this file name in `fs.writeFileSync`

Comment: @katemoss Yes but you are trying to write `undefined` to a file because `translateText` does not return anything.

Comment: but it cannot be possible as I have 3 elements in an array which is passing in `detecText` as element then passing the same element in `translatText()`

Comment: @katemoss You are missing the return statement in `translateText`.

Comment: Oh! but you can see above in `translateText()` **function** I already use return statement

Comment: @katemoss Sorry for the delay there also has to be one outside of the `forEach` in order for the function to return something.

Comment: I have updated outside foreach loop, could you please update your answer with this return ?

Comment: @Palladium02 how can we save this .txt in a folder or another direcotry ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
ImagesNames.forEach(async (element) => {
    try {
      let text = await detecText(element);
      let translatedText = await translateText(text);
      let imagesdir = element.replace("public/", "");
      finaltextsave = imagesdir.replace(".jpg", ".txt");
      fs.writeFileSync(finaltextsave, translatedTexts);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err + element)
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: got error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefinedpublic/8773-20220804-1-Cover Page_5.jpg` here I am removing `public/` and `replacing .jpg` with .txt  from element to save as file name